# Chevy Cavalier 2002 2.2L

Tags: chevrolet, sensor, cavalier

My antifreeze is leaking and my ECT sensor is wet. There is also smoke coming from the hose that's for the reservoir overload.

What's going on?

Comment: Leaking from where? Are you overheating?

Comment: Yah, we definitely need more information here.